# Using a variable for a LINQ property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to pass a property into a method and search for records that match the given value.  The following code does not throw an error, but also does not return any data - ever.  I don't know if the problem is setting the column / property like this, or if something else is wrong... the code looks like:

```
public virtual IList<ReceivingInspection> GetRecordsBySupplier(string property, string value) {
    if (property.Length < 1 || value.Length < 1) return null;
    var result = from ri in _receiveInspectRepository.Table
                 where ri.property == value
                 select ri;
    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect that code to even compile... at least, `ri.property` isn't using the `property` parameter, which presumably you intended it to.

Comment: Is `ri` supposed to have a property with the name of `property`? It would help to know how `ri` is defined.

Comment: I figured it out - It did not have a property called property - I had to iterate through all the properties and see if they were equal.  I don't why it's compiling tho... i use a data mapper and '.property' shouldnt compile.  that's why I was confused and thought maybe I could do it that way.  IDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the items in `_receiveInspectRepository.Table` and use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) to get the value of the `property`

Something like this:

```
Type t = ri.GetType();
PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty(property);
if(prop.GetValue(ri) == value)
{
    dostuff();
}
```